# How to compute null of large sparse matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, null, sparse-matrix

I have a matrix problem in Matlab.
I have a 1million x 1million sparse matrix, and I keep using `null`. Usually, the problem is that I run out of memory. I tried `svds` (which is used for `svd` for sparse matrix), but my issue is I run out of memory as well. Is there a possible work around for large sparse matrices for the `null()` function in Matlab?

Comment: A probably better question would be how to handle the memory in Matlab so that we can add a physical RAM or virtual memory?

Answer (score 5):

In general, the null space of a matrix, or the unitary matrices (`U` and `V`) of the singular values decomposition are *NOT* sparse even if the input matrix is sparse. Therefore, if you try to work with a 1M-by-1M matrix, even though it is sparse, the outputs of your operations are  NOT and therefore you run out of memory.

What can you do?
If your input matrix has a certain structure to it (in addition to its sparseness) you might find some algebraic method to take advantage of this structure.
Another path you should consider, is why you need to compute the null space of the matrix? Can you achieve the same goal without explicitly estimating the null space?

Comment: To add an example of a structure that would help you : having a matrix that is block-diagonal would allow you to split your problem into several smaller ones, thus allowing you to compute your null space

Comment: Good there! And the size of each element in a sparse matrix is roughly 3 times the size of a double.

Comment: How would I create the block diagonal?